# What's best way to create Word doc from template by pulling values from another file?

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word

I currently have a macro which prompts for person initials. After initials are provided, the macro prompts for addressee information. Once that information is provided in different prompts, the macro pulls a specific template for the initials entered at the beginning and populates merge fields with the data entered in the other prompts. The final result is a letter. The template already contains the senders information, address, phone numbers, etc.  This is the current, working solution.

The problem is, there are hundreds of letter templates, one for each person. When something global changes like email domain, all the templates need to be updated and it takes forever to do it.

I would like to keep the senders information in a single repository (.csv, .txt, whatever works best) [call it "DB"] and a single letter template. Then, I want to modify the macro to still prompt for initials, but then instead of opening that person's letter template, I want it to open the "single" template and populate the sender's information from the "DB."  The macro would still prompt for the addressee information because of course, this changes all the time. I'm looking to improve the way the sender's templates are being maintained. So, if something global changes, only one document needs to be revised and may be easier to do with Find/Replace than opening hundreds of docs for editing.

Since there are so many possible solutions, I'm asking for your opinion on what would be the best way to do it. I'm thinking about storing in csv file, but then, how do I find a particular sender in the csv? By searching for their initials? and how would that look like in Word VBA?

Comment: You can store the information in a table in Excel: you can use Word to start Excel, open the file, and search for the id to find the other information.

Comment: This would be better asked in SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or on another forum devoted to using Word. It is really not, at this stage, a programming question and is not suited to Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: «It is really not, at this stage, a programming question» How so? The OP has already said «the macro pulls a specific template for the initials entered at the beginning and populates merge fields with the data entered in the other prompts». Clearly, a macro solution is called for.

Comment: Thank you, @TimWilliams. I decided to go this route you suggested and it's partially working. I need a bit of help and will create a new, programming oriented question.